# ArrayList - Insert method

Tags: powershell

I declare an ArrayList using:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arr = @("foo", "bar", "some", "string")
```

..Then verify its type:

```
$arr.GetType()
```

But inserting a new value, using `Insert()` returns an error:

```
$arr.Insert("anotherstring")
```

`Cannot find an overload for "Insert" and the argument count: "1".`

What does this error message mean? What is the correct format when using this method?

Is there a better way to append items to the ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is to add an element.

```
$arr.Add("anotherstring")
```

The error you're getting with insert is because this method inserts an element in a given position of the array. It takes two arguments: position and element. Since you pass only one argument, it raises an error.

Comment: Thanks - `$arr | Get-Member` does not display the `Add` method. Do you know why?

Comment: Because you're piping array elements, not the array itself.

Comment: @LightningWar `Get-Member -InputObject $arr` would get you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the index of the element you're inserting, in other words the place where it will be placed.

```
$arr.Insert(1,"anotherstring")
```

After that your array will be like this

```
@("foo", "anotherstring", "bar", "some", "string")
```

New element of the array has index of 1

Answer (score 0):

You can see the arguments expected like this, running the method without parentheses:

```
[Collections.ArrayList]$arr = echo foo bar some string
$arr.Insert
```

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Insert(int index, System.Object value)
void IList.Insert(int index, System.Object value)
```